# Any way to cancel a local notification from app delegate that is about to fire?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm in a situation where I need to cancel a local notification that is about to fire. I don't want to remove it but only cancel it for the current time. For context: I don't want to remove the notification because I have it set up to fire every day at a different hour, and it's just not convenient to delete & recreate given the app is notification heavy. Thank you.

Comment: You say "I need to". Who is "I"? If it is the running app — that is, if the app is running and frontmost when the notification fires — the user will see nothing and no harm done.

Answer (score 0):

Is masking the notification processing code a convenient solution?
So you will keep your notification setup while have the ability to enable/disable its effect by simply using a bool flag.